# SignalR Invoke issue

Tags: c#, java, android, signalr

I use the signalR android implementation : https://github.com/erizet/SignalA and I have some problem to use it.

I initialize my HubConnection like this:

```
String url = "http://www.myurl.com";
con = new HubConnection(url, getActivity(), new LongPollingTransport())
{
    @Override
    public void OnStateChanged(StateBase oldState, StateBase newState) {
        switch(newState.getState())
        {
        case Connected:

            ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
            test.add("header");
            test.add("0");
            test.add("data");
            test.add("pleyh");

            hub.Invoke("SendConnection", test, new HubInvokeCallback() {

                @Override
                public void OnResult(boolean arg0, String arg1) {
                    Log.i("HubConnection", "On result: arg0 = " + arg0 + " arg1 = " + arg1);
                }

                @Override
                public void OnError(Exception arg0) {
                    Log.i("HubConnection", "On error: arg0 = " + arg0.getMessage());
                }
            });
            break;
        case Disconnected:
            Log.i("HubConnection", "Disconnected");
            stopSignalA();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

After that, I initialize my HubProxy and start the connection:

```
try {
    hub = con.CreateHubProxy("GameManager");

} catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
hub.On("addNewMessageToPage", new HubOnDataCallback() 
{
    @Override
    public void OnReceived(JSONArray args) {
        Log.i("HubConnection", "OnReceived " + args.toString());
        for(int i=0; i<args.length(); i++)
        {
            Log.i("HubConnection", "OnReceived -> addNewMessageToPage = " + args.opt(i).toString());
        }
    }
});
con.Start();
```

It seems that everything is working properly because the negotiate succeed and I received a JSON with a ConnectionToken. The problem is when I do an invoke when I received an OnStateChanged, when I know I am connected,

**I received this error:**

> ```
> {"I":"0","E":"'SendConnection' method could not be resolved.","T":"   at
> ```
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.NullMethodDescriptor.b_*0(IHub
>   emptyHub, Object[] emptyParameters)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.Incoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext
>   context)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where
>   exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubPipelineModule.<>c*_DisplayClass1.<b_*0>d*_3.MoveNext()"}

**This is what I send to the server:**

```
{"H":"gamemanager","A":["header","0","data","user"],"M":"SendConnection","I":"0"}
```

The error say that the method "SendConnection" does not exist but it does. Someone already had this problem? Or something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1:**

Definition on the Hub and methods definitions:

```
public class GameManager : Hub
    {
        [HubMethodName("sendConnection")]
        public void SendConnection(string Json)
        {
            Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).addNewMessageToPage("[SendConnection] Connection Established: " + Json);
        }

        [HubMethodName("sendToRoom")]
        public void SendToRoom(string message)
        {
            Clients.Group(FindRoomFromConnectionId()._room).addNewMessageToPage("[sendToRoom]: " + message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please paste the code that you are trying to invoke. Seems the method name you are invoking has problem. Also give the hub method definition.

Comment: I also try hub.Invoke("sendConnection" ...); but it is the same.

Comment: from the error message "{"I":"0","E":"'SendConnection' method could not be resolved.","T":"   at" I can see that you are calling the method name in PascalCase. Can you try to change them to camelcase as you have defined the method name? That should solve the problem

Comment: Do you mean hub.Invoke("sendConnection", ...);? I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using too many parameters when calling sendConnection. Try to change your code to something like this:

```
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>(1);
        test.add("only one argument");
```

Comment: The server need to have the "header" and "data" value. So how do I  proceed?

Comment: First, verify that this is the issue. Then the simplest solution is to change your GameManager hub. Change to SendConnection(string header, string data) eg.